# Log4j messages containing (?:method:?) instead of class name

Tags: java, log4j

My log4j messages are not including the class names:

```
[INFO] 22:41 (?: decodeDirectory :?)
```

Any idea why that would be so?

log4j.properties reads like so:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, logfile, console

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=ExifImageRA.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{mm:ss} (%F:%M:%L)%n%m%n%n

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] %d{mm:ss} (%F:%M:%L)%n%m%n%n
```

Comment: Please provide log4j configuration, code samples, etc.  No one can help you with so little information.

Comment: @benw - if i set `debug=true` for javac in my ant script the INFO level messages now display the corresponding class names. Is it neccessary to have `debug=true` in order to see this level of detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what is actually missing from your log messages are the source file name (%F) and the line number (%L).

- According to the `javac` Ant task: the `debug` attribute *"[i]ndicates whether source should be compiled with debug information; defaults to off. If set to off, -g:none will be passed on the command line ... "*.
- According to the `javac` manual, the source filename and line numbers are omitted from the `.class` file if you compile with `javac -g:none`.

Hence, your log message lossage is a direct consequence of removing `debug="true"` from the `javac` task in your Ant build file.

Comment: This looks correct - I'd just like to add it's a bad practice to log the source file name and line number in any production setting - log4j javadocs warn these are *very slow* operations

Comment: @matt b: one way around this is to log asynchronously. I have found that for some applications, this information is indispensable. Asynchronous logging isn't a silver bullet, but it helps quite a bit.

Comment: I believe log4j will still resolve these tokens to the source file name and line number at the time the log message is created, so I'm not sure how asynchronous logging would help - I believe the only thing done asynchronously is the I/O to output the message